# Using ASP.net model in a javascript code. Any other approach other than using <text>?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I am currently getting some data from my controllers which I am using in my cshtml file.
Technically this data needs to be used only by javascript. So I am doing this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var responses = [];

    @foreach (var logItem in @Model.items)
    {
        <text>
        action = '@Html.Raw(@logItem.ActionString)';   
        actions.push(action);  
        </text>
    }

   SomeJSFunciton(actions);
});
```

The above solves the problem however there are two issues with that

1. The text of all this gets written on the page source in the
   `$(document).ready function`
2. I would like to call a js function on
   action before inserting it in the array. I am not sure how to do
   that ?

Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing code like this will become painful as the complexity increases. Something I've had luck with is encoding the server data into JSON like so:

```
var myServerData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(myServerData));
```

This way you will have your server data in JSON format, and you'll be able to write all of your code in JavaScript. So your code would become:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myServerData.length; i++){
    action = myServerData[i]['ActionString'];
    // Here would be where you would call your function before inserting into array
    actions.push(action);
}
SomeJsFunctions(actions);
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense